# Create multiple image sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've have an image slider but I need more than one slider on the same page.  Is it possible to copy my function so it does not interfere with the original?

HTML

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
}
#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {

            $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

            setInterval(function() { 
              $('#slideshow > div:first')
                .fadeOut(1000)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1000)
                .end()
                .appendTo('#slideshow');
            },  3000);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if creating your own function is really necessary for this. Horen gave a good answer, but when implementing it, you realize that the code needs to be tweaked slightly to handle the code distinguishing between appending a child to its own slideshow or another one. For this, I used the `.each()` function to 'sandbox' each slideshow.

There was also an error when you use more than two pictures. The way I handled this is to hide all but the second image on load instead of just hiding the first.

Here's the final markup I used:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F4nTJ/2/

## css

```
.slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
}
.slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

## html

```
<div class="slideshow">
   <div>
       <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg"/>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg"/>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="slideshow">
   <div>
       <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg"/>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

## javascript

```
$(function() {
    $(".slideshow").each(function(){$(this).children().not(":nth-child(2)").hide();});

    setInterval(function() {
        $('.slideshow').each(function(){
            $(this).children(':first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo($(this));
        });
    },  3000);
});
```

Comment: Yes this method seems best.  Is it easy to change the timings or do I need to create separate functions?

Comment: I think an adequate way of achieving this would be to add a `data-interval` attribute to the tag. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/F4nTJ/3/

Comment: data-interval definitely helped.  Although my containers need to be different sizes.  I tried creating separate functions and separate css classes but it doesnt seem to work correctly.  The first container quits functioning and the other 3 keep displaying incorrectly.

Comment: Actually, the top one works for one transition if I give it a small data-interval.  Ill make a JSFiddle to explain.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/trSTk/  (I just used colors instead of generating 12 different photos).  Instead of starting with the first div, they start on the second div, in this case Green.

Comment: @Chaddly. NO. we're not supposed to code that way. Let's say I'm a client and I want 100s of galleries, you would end up pasting 100x the same function all over again? And one day I ask for some changes you would go mad at me :) You need to start to think about coding in a more programmatic way.

Comment: @roXon is right. You always want to program for re-usability. I recommend keeping the idea of using classes and if you need specifics for each slideshow either give it an additional ID or modify the `style` attribute. Here is the new example: http://jsfiddle.net/trSTk/3/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, give it a `class` instead of an `id`

In HTML change `id="slideshow"` to `class="slideshow"` and in CSS and jQuery change `#slideshow` to `.slideshow`

Then you can add a second (and more) slideshow containers to your HTML. Just change the nested image sources and you have different slideshows - fun!

Comment: Great tip, it makes much more sense now.  I did that and the containers are messing up... kind of hard to explain.  Here is a jsfiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xEYVc/  Do I need to create separate functions?

Answer (score 0):

This is the situation when you should consider writing your own plugin:

```
$.fn.slider = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $self = $(this); 
        $(this).children("div:gt(0)").hide();
        setInterval(function() {
            $self.children('div:first')
                .fadeOut(1000)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1000)
                .end()
                .appendTo($self);
        }, 3000);
    });
};

$('.slideshow').slider();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pnp8m/2/

Comment: @roXon with this doctype it's not necessary.